# how to fill values using conditional row in R?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have following dataframe,

[image]

Here I want to add a column 'Constant Vol', where if the 'Year' column is 2006 all the values for 'Constant Vol' should be that od 2006 'Vol'. The result should be like following dataframe.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dplyr`, we can `group_by` `Seg` and get the corresponding `Vol` where `Year = 2006`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Seg) %>%
  mutate(Constnt_Vol = Vol[Year == 2006])

#  Seg    Year   Vol Constnt_Vol
#  <fct> <int> <dbl>       <dbl>
#1 Agri   2006    23          23
#2 Agri   2007    29          23
#3 Agri   2008    16          23
#4 Agri   2009    31          23
#5 Auto   2006    12          12
#6 Auto   2007    34          12
#7 Auto   2008    45          12
#8 Auto   2009    32          12
```

and in `data.table` that would be

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, Constnt_Vol :=  Vol[Year == 2006], Seg]
```

This is assuming you have only one row with `Year = 2006` in each `Seg`, if there are multiple we can use `which.max` to get the first one. (`Vol[which.max(Year == 2006)]`).

**data**

```
df <- data.frame(Seg = rep(c("Agri", "Auto"), each  =4), 
       Year  =2006:2009, Vol = c(23, 29, 16, 31, 12, 34, 45, 32))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   group_by(Seg) %>%
   mutate(Constnt_Vol = Vol[match(2006, Year)])
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame(Seg = rep(c("Agri", "Auto"), each  =4), 
       Year  =2006:2009, Vol = c(23, 29, 16, 31, 12, 34, 45, 32))
```